# cannot create neither Shim nor Stub

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, portable-class-library, microsoft-fakes

In Visual Studio 2013 in existing test project when I create fake assembly (System.dll for example) - nothing happens. No System.Fake assembly created.

But once I try to do it in new project (console application) it works nice and neat.

How to make it do in my existing Solution?  What happens ?

Comment: Do you see any messages in the output window?

Comment: Yes I do. Nothing informative.

Comment: The fake dll file is created but not attached to the project. I simply added it by hands. Seems this is another usual VS 2013 bug for Portable libraries :(